# How to prevent a submit button on a form to be clicked multiple times in VUEJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I want to prevent users from clicking on the submit button multiple times. How would I accomplish that in the following template and script?

*Excerpt of template:*

```html
<form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
  <b-button
            v-on:click="disable"
            variant="danger"
            type="submit"
          >
          Compléter
  </b-button>
</form>
```

*..and script:*

```
onSubmit() {
  this.$v.status.$touch();
  if (!this.$v.$invalid) {
    /////
  }
},
```

Comment: do you want to prevent the submit when clicking on Compléter button?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want

Answer (score 4):

You could set a Boolean flag (e.g., named `submitting`) that disables the button during the form submission process. The `<b-button>` supports a [disabled state](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/button/) with the `disabled` attribute, which could be [bound](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) to `submitting`:

```html
<b-button :disabled="submitting">Compléter</b-button>
```

*Example:*

```html
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
    <b-button :disabled="submitting">Compléter</b-button>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      submitting: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async onSubmit() {
      if (!this.submitting) {
        this.submitting = true
        try {
          await this.longSubmit()
        } finally {
          this.submitting = false
        }
      }
    }
    //...
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/PoqwNwy)